# using types from dll A in dll B

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll

I have the following situation: there is an application, say App.exe, which loads a dll created by me, let's call it A.dll. The dll uses SQLite to store data, and accesses the methods referenced from SQLite.dll (let's say). Now, in A.dll, if I declare a global `SQLiteConnection` then when App.exe loads my library it complains that "the type A.A could not be loaded". If, however, I declare it locally in the constructor, everything seems fine.

This is not a huge problem, but since that is a database connection I'd like to have the variable global, then just establish a connection in the constructor and use it in code. So, is there any way around this?

PS: As you can probably tell, I'm rather a noob when it comes to C# & .NET. If this is a stupid question, I apologize :).

Comment: If you have a DLL that inherits from another DLL that inherits from another DLL, you must add a reference to the last DLL in the first one.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'global SQLiteConnection'? C# doesn't have global variables.

Comment: @Tico Yes, I have done that, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled would it?

Comment: @zmbq My bad, wrong term, I meant a variable declared in the class, not locally in a function.

Comment: Oddly enough it does compile, but the error appears in runtime

Comment: @szczurcio Are you sure both dlls (`A.dll` and `SQLLite.dll`) are near the `App.exe`? Another thought: does the project for `A.dll` target the sampe framework as the project for `App.exe`? (it might be `App.exe` uses `.Net 4.0` and `A.dll` uses `.Net 4.0 Client Profile`)

Comment: @DarkWalker 1) Yes, I remembered to put them in the same directory. 2)
Well, as I said I'm a noob and hence I'm not really sure ;). However, I have made another DLLs that don't use SQLLite.dll and compiled them in the very same way; they work perfectly, so I guess I'm targeting the right framework.

Comment: @szczurcio You can check what framework you are targeting by selecting project in `Solution Explorer`, selecting `Properties` in the context menu (right click) and checking out `Application` tab. More info here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Your `app.exe` has to reference the sqlite library, too.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Are you absolutely sure? As I said, if I declare them locally in the constrctor there are no problems.

Comment: Yes, I have, however strangely enough now I'm getting an error saying  "could not load SQLiteException from assembly..." even though when I compile a regular executable everything seems fine... I think I'll use XML instead, this isn't fun at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `SQLite.dll` can't be located by your application at runtime. It's probably *not* in the same folder as `app.exe`, or at least, not the `app.exe` you are running.

Clean the solution from Visual Studio, then rebuild. Check your app/bin/debug folder and makes sure there's an `SQLite.DLL` there.

Comment: The app.exe is not developed by me, it is a ready application which I'm developing plugins for. I've made sure SQLite.dll is located in the folder I'm running app.exe from.

Comment: Ooooooh. They may be loading plugins in a way that prevents other DLLs from being loaded.